# NodeMCU firmware does not run after downloading firmware

Tags: nodemcu, esp32

I am trying to download the NodeMCU firmware, but after downloading

```
rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
flash read err, 1000
Falling back to built-in command interpreter.
OK
```

The NodeMCU documentation,[Flashing the firmware](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/flash/#esptoolpy), this describes the general command format. The command I used was:

```
sudo espressif/esptool/repo/esptool.py --port /dev/ttyS8 write_flash -fm dio 0x00000 nodemcu/repo/bin/0x00000.bin
```

Note, I am running this within Windows WSL Debian based distro hence ttyS8.

My assumption why this doesn't work is due to the message seen within the console.  After a bit of searching I did find some information within the letscontrolit/ESPEasy forum, found [here](https://github.com/letscontrolit/ESPEasy/issues/2202) by voducng.  His response was the following:

```
You need to flash the bootloader. So under Windows10/cmd:

    I do erase: flasherase.cmd:
    esptool.exe --chip esp32 --port COM11 --baud 256000 --before default_reset --after hard_reset erase_flash

    I do use flash the boot loader: flashbootloader.cmd:
    esptool.exe --chip esp32 --port COM11 --baud 256000 --before default_reset --after hard_reset write_flash -z --flash_mode dio --flash_freq 80m --flash_size detect 0x8000 partitions2.bin 0xe000 boot_app0.bin 0x1000 bootloader.bin

    and flashfirmware.cmd:
    esptool.exe --chip esp32 --port COM11 --baud 256000 --before default_reset --after hard_reset write_flash -z --flash_mode dio --flash_freq 80m --flash_size detect 0x10000 firmware.bin
```

I am able to issue commands 1 and 3, but I can't execute command #2 since I don't know where the file partitions2.bin is.  There are a couple of bootloader files I found in the esptool repo, but not sure which one to use.

Here is the listing after searching for these files

```
user@machine:/mnt/c/MyFiles/Projects/espressif$ find . -iname *partition*.bin
./esp-idf/components/nvs_flash/test/partition_encrypted.bin
./esp-idf/components/wear_levelling/test/test_partition_v1.bin
./esptool/repo/test/images/partitions_singleapp.bin
user@machine:/mnt/c/MyFiles/Projects/espressif$ find . -iname *boot*.bin
./esptool/repo/test/images/bootloader_esp32.bin
./esptool/repo/test/images/bootloader_esp32s2beta.bin
./esptool/repo/test/images/esp8266_sdk/boot_v1.4(b1).bin
./esptool/repo/test/secure_images/bootloader-encrypted-conf0.bin
./esptool/repo/test/secure_images/bootloader-encrypted-conf3.bin
./esptool/repo/test/secure_images/bootloader-encrypted-conf9.bin
./esptool/repo/test/secure_images/bootloader-encrypted-confc.bin
./esptool/repo/test/secure_images/bootloader-encrypted.bin
./esptool/repo/test/secure_images/bootloader.bin
./esptool/repo/test/secure_images/bootloader_digested.bin
./esptool/repo/test/secure_images/bootloader_signed.bin
```

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the Lua firmware? esp32 or esp8266?

Comment: @Juraj, I am not sure how to answer your question properly.  I cloned the NodeMCU repo, built the project by using `make`.  Then tried to download the firmware to an ESP32 [this one](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0718T232Z/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Comment: the esp32 dev board in link is not NodeMcu. "NodeMCU" is a name for a dev board and for a firmware. The NodeMcu firmware is a Lua language interpreter. NodeMcu boards are used more without the Lua firmware then with it and the Lua firmware can be used with any esp8266 and esp32, not only with NodeMcu board

Comment: @Juraj, thanks for the info, but I still don't see how this helps my cause. I believe I stated the description correctly, but if it isn't please describe how it isn't so I can correct the description of my question.  The NodeMCU is the firrmware, as I understand it, which runs LUA scripts (so, it isn't Lua firmware).  All I am trying to do is download NodeMCU firmware built from the repo to this board.  Perhaps these boards already come with the NodeMCU firmware and I am wasting my time.  Still, if they do I would still like to download updated NodeMCU firmware when it is available.

Comment: The `master` and `dev` branches are for ESP8266 - not sure which one you built. `dev-esp32` is for ESP32. I noticed that you link to the `master` documentation. Take note of the branch toggle in the lower right corner on the documentation site. For ESP32 you would simply run `make flash`.

Comment: @MarcelStör, I didn't realize there were specific builds/branches which makes complete sense.  This is probably my issue, I hope. I will give your suggestion a try. Thank you very much.   You might consider posting an response so we can give credit where credit is due.

Comment: Will happily do so once it's confirmed that it actually helped at all :)

Comment: @lordhog The title is a little bit misleading, as "downloading" lets (me) think on sending things from a embedded device towards me (i.e. my host machine). Maybe write "after flashing firmware"